# Why does sampling without replacement in my function just duplicate my output?

Tags: r, pca, resampling

I've written two functions, one works, one doesn't. Was wondering why sampling in the first example just duplicates my results - why is it not creating new shufflings without replacement for each replication?

Probably missing something obvious, but not sure what...

```
       D1<- matrix(runif(10*12, 0, 2), ncol=12))

       perm_fun1 <- function(DF){
         # permute each column
         smp <- sample(1:ncol(DF), replace=F)
         new_data <- DF[, smp]
         # run PCA
         pc.perm.out<-prcomp(new_data,center=T, scale.=T)
         # get the proportion of variance of each PC.perm
         pve.perm=(pc.perm.out$sdev^2/sum(pc.perm.out$sdev^2))
       }


      perm_fun2 <- function(DF){
         # permutation each column
         new_data <- apply(DF, 2, sample)
         # run PCA
         pc.perm.out<-prcomp(new_data,center=T, scale.=T)
         # get the proportion of variance of each PC.perm
         pve.perm=(pc.perm.out$sdev^2/sum(pc.perm.out$sdev^2))
       }

       out_smp1 <- sapply(1:5, function(i) perm_fun1(D1))
       out_smp2 <- sapply(1:5, function(i) perm_fun2(D1))
```

out_smp1 just gets a 10x5 output, but each value in each column for each row is repeated. How would I change perm_fun1 for it not to do that?

EDIT:

function 2 is the correct one for my purpose.

Useful links
https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-102-should-you-use-pca-how-many-components-to-use-how-to-interpret-them-da0c8e3b11f0

Other similar problem
[PCA explained variance is the same on permutations of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051628/pca-explained-variance-is-the-same-on-permutations-of-data)

Article they reference which is behind paywall on Medium
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-tune-hyperparameters-of-tsne-7c0596a18868

Comment: Without a reproducible example we can't be sure, but I assume it's because you're written `new_data <- DF[, smp]` rather than `new_data <- DF[smp,]` - you're shuffling the columns but leaving the rows in the same order.

Comment: @PGSA thank you for the comment - my rows are samples and columns variables, using D1 as a simplified example of data. I have 12 cols here and 10 rows. I want to shuffle my columns, not rows, and I believe new_data <- DF[smp,], would get an error as I don't have 12 rows, so the subscript would be out of bounds.

Comment: Again: f1 shuffles column order, while f2 shuffles row order. What do you really want to achieve with the code? Sounds like a XY problem.

Comment: @MichaelM I would like to decorrelate my columns, I'm using this code but its in Python, https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-102-should-you-use-pca-how-many-components-to-use-how-to-interpret-them-da0c8e3b11f0, (the choosing principal components section) so its a guess what they're doing, might be silly question, but would shuffling rows decorrelate my columns? Somewhat confused. I ultimately would like to see which PCs are relevant, so am using permutation and then calculating p value (not shown in code above).

Comment: Why would rearranging columns change a PCA analysis? Correlation is a mathematical property of the data in the columns, putting them in different order will not change that.

Comment: I read the Blog post. They shuffle the rows within column individually to break any dependence. Then apply PCA and derive some null distribution, as in a permutation test. Your f2 starts doing this.

Comment: @MichaelM, thank you Michael, much appreciated!

Comment: @Adam9: for instance, a permutation test of a correlation coefficient works similarly: shuffle rows in one of the columns "restores" the situation under the null hypothesis of no correlation. You calculate the correlation per permutation and get the approximate distribution of the correlation coefficient under the null. The idea in the blog is very similar, focusing on a PCA related statistic of interest.